# How to generate a random set? (haskell)

Tags: haskell

Here is how set is defined:

```
module SetOrd (Set(..),emptySet,isEmpty,inSet,subSet,insertSet,
           deleteSet,powerSet,takeSet,(!!!),list2set,unionSet) 

where

import Data.List (sort) 

{-- Sets implemented as ordered lists without duplicates --} 

newtype Set a = Set [a] deriving (Eq,Ord)

instance (Show a) => Show (Set a) where
showsPrec _ (Set s) str = showSet s str

showSet []     str = showString "{}" str
showSet (x:xs) str = showChar '{' ( shows x ( showl xs str))
 where showl []     str = showChar '}' str
       showl (x:xs) str = showChar ',' (shows x (showl xs str))
```

And then I want to system generate a random set like:

```
getSetInt :: IO Set
getSetInt = do 
            d <- getRandomInt 10
            n <- getRandomInt 5
            m <- getRandomInt 5
            getSetI d n m

getSetI :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO Set
getSetI _ _ 0 = return (Set [])
getSetI d n m = do 
        f <- getRandomSet d n
        fs <- getSetI d n (m-1)
        return (Set (f:fs))

getRandomSet :: Int -> Int -> IO Set
getRandomSet _ 0 = return (Set [])
getRandomSet d n = do
                f <- getRandomInt d
                fs <- getRandomSet d (n-1)
                return (Set (f:fs))
```

But here is something wrong with my codes. 
`Expecting one more argument to "Set"
    In the type signature for "getSetInt": getSetInt :: IO Set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The First problem

Your set is defined as

```
newtype Set a = ...
```

This means that `Set` has kind `* -> *`, in other words, you need to pass it a type for it to parametrize over.

Think of it like

```
 template<typename T>
 class foo{};
```

The word `foo` is meaningless on it's own.

Since you're using `Int`s everywere I'm assuming you want

```
 IO (Set Int)
```

---

#### The rest of the code

Next in `getSetI`, the line

```
 fs <- getSetI d n (m-1)
```

Should be

```
 Set fs <- getSetI d n (m-1)
```

since you want to use the underlying list, not the `Set` interface in later code.

Also you never mention what `getRandomInt` is, but assuming that works something like

```
 getRandomInt a = randomRIO (0, a)
```

from the `random` package.

The rest of the code actually contained somewhere around 10-12 errors so I'm not going to describe every single one here. The main one is that

```
 return Set foo
```

Is wrong, this passes `return` 2 arguments, you want

```
 return (Set foo)
```

Also, `getSetI` seems to make `m` random sets and then tries to lump them into a `IO (Set (Set Int))`, what do you want that to do exactly?

Comment: OH! thanks a lot!! i figured it out now. Haskell is so difficult for me.

Comment: @zll19910516 Happy to help, good luck with Haskell! Don't worry, everyone has trouble at first